# Navigation Lightning Page via App Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, navigation

I've build some Lightning Components and drag-and-dropped them on a Lightning Page which was build via the Lightning App Builder.

1. How can you navigate from a record detail page to my newly build Lightning Page? I've tried it with a Lightning Component and Lightning Action, but no luck.
2. Is it possible to pass along the recordId or another parameter to the components that are on that Lightning Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your question is not that clear, but in general, if you want to navigate to a lightning component, use [force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm), if not - please specify exactly where and what exactly you are trying to achive.
2. You can pass the record id as a parameter - you need to implement `force:hasRecordId` and create an attribute `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" access="GLOBAL" />` on your component markup, after that you can use in your component controller the id: `var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");` and send the id to a new url or do whatevery you want with it. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm) is a good explanation for it, and [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html) is a good example.